How can I replacing columns between csv files using columns headers as match in bash scripting?
I am new to bash scripting and I am putting together a simple script to take a column from one csv file and then use it to replace a column in another csv file.
I managed to do it with awk this way
awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, 'FNR==NR{hash[FNR]=$0; next}{$8 = hash[FNR]}1' test4.csv test1.csv > test5.csv

This works, however the csv files that I would work with, don't always have the same numbers of columns so for example, $8 in test1.csv is not always $8.
I want to standardise this script by using the columns header to do the replacement rather than the number of column.
Can anyone help me?
cat test1.csv 
Sample_ID,Sample_Name,Sample_Plate,Sample_Well,I7_Index_ID,index,I5_Index_ID,index2,Sample_Project,Description
1,O_gis,1,A01,UDI_55,GACAGTAA,UDI_55,GTAATCGC,,
2,A_blam,1,B01,UDI_56,CCTTCGCA,UDI_56,AAGTGATG,,

cat test2.csv
2xedni
GCGATTAC
CATCACTT

Desired output:
Sample_ID,Sample_Name,Sample_Plate,Sample_Well,I7_Index_ID,index,I5_Index_ID,index2,Sample_Project,Description

1,O_gis,1,A01,UDI_55,GACAGTAA,UDI_55,GCGATTAC,,
2,A_blam,1,B01,UDI_56,CCTTCGCA,UDI_56,CATCACTT,,

